# Using Initializer List in Polymorphism in C++ creating confusion as in place of variable a class is used

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream> 
using namespace std;
 
class Shape {
   protected:
      int width, height;
      
   public:
      Shape( int a = 0, int b = 0){
         width = a;
         height = b;
      }
      int area() {
         cout << "Parent class area :" <<endl;
         return 0;
      }
};
class Rectangle: public Shape {
   public:
      Rectangle( int a = 0, int b = 0):Shape(a, b) { }
      
      int area () { 
         cout << "Rectangle class area :" <<endl;
         return (width * height); 
      }
};

class Triangle: public Shape {
   public:
      Triangle( int a = 0, int b = 0):Shape(a, b) { }
      
      int area () { 
         cout << "Triangle class area :" <<endl;
         return (width * height / 2); 
      }
};

int main() {
   Shape *shape;
   Rectangle rec(10,7);
   Triangle  tri(10,5);

   shape = &rec;
   
   shape->area();

   shape = &tri;
   
   shape->area();
   
   return 0;
}
```

in this example I am not able to understand the function of

```
Rectangle( int a = 0, int b = 0):Shape(a, b) { }
```

and

```
Triangle( int a = 0, int b = 0):Shape(a, b) { }
```

I understand this is similar to the syntax of Initializer List in C++, but with Initializer List we can intialize any **variable** like

```
class_apple (int var) : x(var) {}
```

so here x=var, but in above code in place of the **variable**

```
:Shape(a, b)
```

the Shape class is used? what does this achieve and what does it mean for polymorphism?

Comment: It's calling its base class' constructor.

Answer (score 0):

```
Rectangle( int a = 0, int b = 0) : Shape(a, b) { }
```

Rectangle is a `derived` class of `Shape`. `:Shape(a,b)` passes the arguments `a` and `b`, received by the Rectangle constructor to its base class.
When a `Rectangle` instance is created it uses `Shape(int a, int b)` constructor to assign values to `width` and `height`.

The same is true with `Triangle` since it too derives from `Shape`.

Now consider the following hierarchy.

```
struct Base {
  int x,y;
  Base(int a, int b) : x(a), y(b) {}
};

struct Derived : Base {
  int m;
  Derived(int a, int b, int c) : Base(a, b), m(c) {}
};
```

In the above example `Derived` class passes arguments `a` and `b` to the base class constructor while using the member initialization list to initialize `m` with the value of `c`.